# Hotwire Turbo Frame in Django application stops django-bootstrap-datepicker-plus from showing

Tags: javascript, django, datepicker, turbo-frames, hotwire

In my Django App I use a Turbo Frame in a DetailView. The Turbo Frame loads a form into the DetailView. This form has a datefield for which I use a Datepicker (django-bootstrap-datepicker-plus). If I call the form directly the Datepicker works just fine, but when the form is called into the DetailView via Turbo Frame the Datepicker does not show.

Any suggestions on how to solve this and whats the underlying issue is?

Best

I tried to use Stimulus to initialize the Datepicker but so far I have no success and I also couldnt find any Q&A in the Internet.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.